# Dim rest of page on menu hover - 'flashing' issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, jquery-effects

I am attempting to dim the rest of the page on hover of my websites mega menu. Although the effect is working to some extent, it seems to flash on and off, or flash off and then not come back on again (even if I hover back over the correct element).

```js
jQuery('.navigation,#mainMenu,.mega-menu-content,.mega-menu-item').hover(function() {
  jQuery('.darkness').fadeTo(0, 1);
}, function() {
  jQuery('.darkness').fadeTo(300, 0, function() {
    jQuery(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.darkness {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
  <ul id="mainMenu">
    <li>
      <a href="mywebsite">Standard Item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu-item">
      <a href="mywebsite">Dropdown Item</a>
      <li>
        <div class="mega-menu-content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="level1">
                  <a href="mywebsite">Sub-Category</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="darkness"></div>
```

The darkness div, gives the rest of the page the darkening element (the CSS works fine). It's the jquery I am struggling with and I'm hoping someone can help?

As I say above, it's a flashing effect I am getting at the moment, even when hovering on elements that are included in the jquery code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not only with the jQuery but with the CSS .

you set `z-index:100` to `.darkness` but don't set a `z-index` to the hovering element. so when the `darkness` appears, it is on top of the `navigation`

being on top of the `navigation` , the `navigation` is no longer hovered so ( because of the JQ function ) `darkness` hides again.

when `darkness` is hidden you can hover on `navigation` so it appears again, and then again you cannot hover the `navigation` because `darkness` is on top and hides again. and so on -> thus the 'flashing' problem.

set `position:relative;z-index:9999` to `.navigation` or bigger than z-index of `darkness` and in JQ just use `.navigation` ( it contains the rest of the elements so the hover will work even if you hover on `li` ) .

see snippet below

```js
jQuery('.navigation').hover(function() {
  jQuery('.darkness').fadeTo(0, 1);
}, function() {
  jQuery('.darkness').fadeTo(300, 0, function() {
    jQuery(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.darkness {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
/*added css*/
.navigation {
 position:relative;
  z-index:101;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
  <ul id="mainMenu">
    <li>
      <a href="mywebsite">Standard Item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mega-menu-item">
      <a href="mywebsite">Dropdown Item</a>
      <li>
        <div class="mega-menu-content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="level1">
                  <a href="mywebsite">Sub-Category</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="darkness"></div>
```